# Is $L$ an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> For $p(x)\in\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R)$, define $L:\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R^3$ by
> $$
> L(p(x))=[p(0) \space\space  p'(0) \space\space p''(0)]^T.
> $$
> Here, $\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R)$ is the set of all real polynomials with degree at most $2$.

I'm asked to verify that $L$ is an isomorphism.

I begin by noticing that only the $p(0)$ element has the possibility of having a nonzero value (the constant term). We can write
$$
\mathrm{range}(L)=\mathrm{span} \{[1 \space\space 0 \space\space 0]^T\},
$$
which implies $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{range}(L))=1$. However, $\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R))=3$ so $L$ cannot be surjective and therefore cannot be an isomorphism.

Is my reasoning correct here? This question is part of a larger one and this verification step seems like something that should be simple to show. The fact that I'm getting a different result raises doubts. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that only $p(0)$ can be nonzero? Try some examples (say, $p(x) =x$), and you might see where you have errors in your approach. (Also, minor correction: $\mathcal{P}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ consists of real polynomials with degree *at most* $2$.)

Comment: Calculate $L(ax^2+bx+c).$

Comment: @AlexWertheim Ah, you're absolutely right! I had overlooked the degree $1$ terms and gone straight for the constants. Thank you for the correction as well :)

Comment: why the upvoting? the hint that says
$$L(1)=[1\ \ 0\ \ 0]^{\top},$$
$$L(x)=[0\ \ 1\ \ 0]^{\top},$$
$$L(x^2)=[0\ \ 0\ \ 2]^{\top},$$ shows that $L$ maps a domain's basis in a codomain's basis and by linear extension you will get an isomorphism

Comment: The result can be an indirect consequence of the taylor series; A polynomial's coefficients can be thought to be determined by value of it's derivative at a point. [Check out this article I wrote for more info](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123)

Answer (score 1):

We know that if $ B $ is a basis of $ \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}) $, then $ Range(T) = Span(T(B)) $.

Let's take the standard basis $ B = \{1, x, x^2\} $.

You can check that:

$ T(1) = [1, 0, 0]^T $

$ T(x) = [0, 1, 0]^T $

$ T(x^2) = [0, 0, 2]^T $

The set $ C=\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\} $ is linearly independent (check!) and has exactly $ 3 $ elements. $ \dim(\mathbb{R}^3)=3$, which means $ C $ is a basis for $ \mathbb{R}^3 $, and therefore $ Range(T)= \mathbb{R}^3 $.

There is a theorem stating that if $ V $ and $ W $ are two finite-dimensional vector spaces of dimension $ n $ and there exists a linear transformation $ S : V \to W $ such that $ Range(S) = W $, then $ S $ is an isomorphism.

$ \dim(\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}))= \dim(\mathbb{R}^3) $ and therefore, by the theorem above, we know that $ T $ is indeed an isomorphism.